# NSManagedObject class modifying variables to save struct to CoreData is Crashing

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data

I need to save a struct to CoreData. I found and example to wrap the struct in NSManagedObject such as:

```
struct Salary {
    let amount: Double
}

class Employee: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged private var salaryAmount: Double

    var salary: Salary {
        get {
            return Salary(amount: self.salaryAmount)
        }
        set {
            self.salaryAmount = newValue.amount
        }
    }
}
```

What I am not sure is how to add the struct to the NSManagedObject. I am creating the NSManagedObject and then modifying its variable.

```
let employee = Employee() //NSManagedObject
employee.salary = Salary(amount: 1000.00)
```

Doing so causes a crash - *unrecognized selector sent to instance*

I also need this to be saved as an array inside of CoreData of Employee because I want to save multiple structs.

What is the proper way to add the struct to the NSManagedObject?

Thanks.

Comment: `let employee = Employee()`, this should give a compilation error or do you have some custom init? Other than that the code looks ok.

Answer (score 1):

The crash is caused by assigning a value to an attribute of an incorrectly instantiated object.

You must instantiate a `NSManagedObject` by using one of the official initialisers, for example:

```
let employee = Employee(context: yourManagedObjectContext)
```

Comment: “… an incorrectly instantiated object", I don’t understand this part. Wouldn’t we get a runtime error when initializing the object instead of on the line after or even a compiler error?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Apparently not. `let employee = Employee()` is compilable and does not even give a runtime error, but does not result in a valid managed Employee object.

Comment: Ah, maybe that’s because it inherits from NSObject? Well in that case your answer makes sense to me :)

Comment: I did try to initialize with the main context, still was getting a crash. Perhaps then it is the wrong context if I am calling it in the background context. I will try again I get back to it later today.

Comment: I added the the context, now getting an error - App.Employee must have a valid NSEntityDescription. I have existing CoreData that is working and saving fine. Looking for answer, people say to make sure targets are enabled, but I have that set up. Any idea what it could be?

Comment: Make sure the Employee entity is in the Core Data Model design in Xcode. Your Employee class must be public, and also the attributes must be public. The class must be set in the Core Data Model designer. Codegen setting should probably set to Manual. In case of doubt, generate a NSManagedObject Subclass via the Edit menu, as an example, after opening the model in Xcode.